# Why do we no longer refer to Muslim and Hindu women as being 'in Purdah'?

Tags: word-usage

The term *purdah* is used metaphorically in Britain for anyone who stays out of sight. The Chancellor of the Exchequer is said to *go into purdah* (away from the press)before he delivers his annual budget statement.

But although there are many Indian, Pakistani, and Arabic women who wear the full *hijab*, (facial covering), in Britain, I never hear them referred to as *in purdah*.

In former times when Britain governed the sub-continent, *purdah* was an important part of the language, referring to the practice of women over the age of puberty remaining out of sight of men, other than their immediate family.

Comment: This is definitely not a common usage in American English!  But, my suspicion is that it's a nod to changing attitudes.  I would guess that the press is disdainful of the practice.  (Traditional, and culturally appropriate as it may be for some.)

Comment: (Scratches head) My professor friend who studies Indian Muslim women uses this word. I doesn't have much resonance in American culture, and isn't well enough known for metaphorical usage.

Comment: The vaguest of conjectures, so I won't offer it as an answer, but perhaps it was pushed out by a mixture of pressures between 1. The parliamentary sense on the one sense making that definition the main sense English speakers (those of us with some knowledge of GB political procedure anyway) have of it on the one hand, 2. *purdah* was once overused for cases that weren't really purdah, now *hijab* is used for the same cases (inc. not really hijab), 3. you don't meet many women in purdah, because they are in purdah.

Comment: At my grandson's school, in an inner-Manchester suburb, where over 50% of the children speak a language at home which is not English, there are several women who bring and collect their children from school whilst wearing a face covering. Are these women not in purdah? Or does 'purdah' refer to women who never leave the marital home?

Comment: My understanding is it covers both, along with some other cases. Hopefully someone better informed can give us a more definitive answer.

Comment: I have just looked at the OED, which perhaps is what I should have done from the outset. 'Purdah' is the Urdu word for a 'curtain'. It is used as the word for the curtain which screens women from the sight of male strangers. It also refers to a face covering. And it also refers to all these practices. Thus it seems to be an all-encompassing word. But what I still don't understand is why in Britain today where many Asian women seclude themselves in this way, (in France the face covering in public is banned) we do not refer to their being 'in purdah'.

Comment: @DavidM Some argue that people have a fundamental right to wear whatever they choose. others that for women working as schoolteachers or nurses, they should not be allowed to hide their faces. Personally I find it difficult to understand how anyone can teach effectively with their face covered. In a recent court case a judge ruled that the defendant be allowed to wear a covering whilst in the dock, but that if she went into the witness box to testify that she would have to remove it. The argument was that a jury had a need to see her face in order to judge whether she was telling the truth.

Comment: @WS2 I hope no one construed my comment as being anything against a traditional practice.  I'm ambivalent about other people's choices as long as they affect me minimally, and are just that, a choice.  Beyond that, I don't have a dog in the fight.

Comment: "*in France the face covering in public is banned*".  **Nonsense.**  You'd better check your sources -- they are misleading you grossly.  And maybe look up the meaning of "in public".

Comment: @Drew may I suggest you look at the Wiki entry. Please tell me what I am misunderstanding here.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ban_on_face_covering

Comment: My apologies; it appears you are right.  I thought it was only forbidden in publicly provided spaces such as schools, and for public employees during their hours of employment (e.g. a policeman on duty).  Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Purdah literally means a veil or a curtain depending on the context. You certainly can't call all Hindu and Muslim women as people in Purdah as most of them don't follow this system anymore. That might be the reason for the decline in the usage of the term. And yes there are a few fundamentalists who adhere to the religious customs and follow this  practice. But the term purdah might have been used as a derogatory remark to imply that they are backward by sticking to ancient practices. So you might not want to use it. You could however say, they are in a "burka".

Comment: Thank you for that contribution. I didn't realise that the term 'purdah' could be considered derogatory. It is no problem since I have certainly not used it, other than as a query on this site. But I do regularly see women in Manchester who wear a face covering.